# Where and how can I get FX intraday data for use it in R?

Tags: r, market-data, fx, intraday

I need FX data (the most accurate possible) for use in R. 
Right now I have developed a script in Java to download the CSV file (from Oanda) and use this file to read it in R, but I think that is a turn around. 
Someone know a best option to work with R?

Comment: Do you need a time series or a script which can get the price every, let's say, 5 minutes (or 1 hour or 30 seconds or whatever you want)?

Comment: Welcome to quant.SE @ferran87. Maybe you could some of the available R framework to connect with the most common data provider API's (http://www.r-bloggers.com/financial-data-accessible-from-r-part-iii/)

Comment: @Simone Bortolato: yes initially, but the most perfect solution would be tick by tick data. Do you have this script?

Comment: @muffin1974: thank you! I will try every option!

Comment: If you are oper to a different programming behavior, I would suggest you to try with MATLAB: I've been able to download the price of a stock from Yahoo Finance two times every second, with just a loop and a couple of instructions. (I've got a very slow 1mb connection at my home)

Comment: Try these guys... histdata.com

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [TFX](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TFX/index.html) R package.

Answer (score 0):

FX is a very different beast because there's no centralized market and the actual flow you can interact with differs greatly from participant to participant. I would recommend that you only use historical data that you are storing yourself.